# How to create search bar with Dependent Dropdown In react

Tags: javascript, jquery, reactjs, react-native, react-hooks

[image]

I'm looking out for a search bar with Dependent Dropdown In react.

can anyone help me out With these?

Or else do you have any suggestions on how to create with depending on the dropdown for search bar.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Have you tried using react-select library? Its a pretty good one with lot of customisable functionality.
https://www.npmjs.com/package/react-select